# How to record chrome browser session launched in selenium using java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

We run tests in parallel using TestNG in same machine
Currently we are getting screenshots for individual browser sessions , similar to that we need videos for individual browser sessions.

So is there a way to record chrome browser session launched in selenium using java ?

Machines run are 'Windows' (or) 'MAC OSX'

Comment: This sounds a lot like spyware.

Comment: see my revised answer with TestNG example.

Answer (score 0):

These are the most common open-source alternatives:

https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/video-recorder-java

https://github.com/zalando/zalenium

video-recorder-java TestNG example:

```
import com.automation.remarks.video.annotations.Video;
import com.automation.remarks.video.testng.VideoListener;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue;

@Listeners(VideoListener.class)
public class TestNgVideoTest {

    @Test
    @Video
    public void shouldFailAndCreateRecordWithTestName() {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        assert false;
    }

    @Test
    @Video(name = "second_test")
    public void videoShouldHaveNameSecondTest(){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

From repository's readme:

FFMPEG recorder configuration
In order to use ffmpeg type recorder first you need to perform such steps:

Windows
In case of Windows platform you need to download ffmpeg

Just download it and unzip to some folder on you PC. Example C:\ffmpeg

Then set System variable path for ffmpeg. Example

Example: add to PATH variable ;C:\ffmpeg\bin

Also you need to download SendSignalCtrlC.exe utility and put into the folder ffmpeg/bin.

The final result should be folder with ffmpeg, SendSignalCtrlC.exe utilities and System variable that point to this folder.

To be sure that everything works properly, open CMD and perform first command:

```
ffmpeg

The output should look like this:

C:\Users\sepi>ffmpeg
ffmpeg version N-81234-ge1be80a Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 51.100 / 57. 51.100
  libavformat    57. 44.100 / 57. 44.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 49.100 /  6. 49.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20210406)

Comment: Revised my answer with TestNG example. Thanks.

Comment: Above Code didn't work for me
Not able to find bin folder(C:\ffmpeg\bin) after download and extracting ffmpeg software

Comment: @YenikeRaghuRam have you used Maven and implemented the dependency?
See updated answer